# Laravel 5 not seeing Contact page

Tags: apache, laravel, laravel-5

Im new to Laravel.

I have set up my `httpd-vhosts.conf` like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:\Laravel\learning-laravel-5\public"
    ServerName laravel5
    <Directory  "E:\Laravel\learning-laravel-5\public">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and `hosts` file like this

```
127.0.0.1       laravel5
::1             laravel5
```

okay, so in my browser when I enter `laravel5` in the adress bar, I get the Laravel 5 welocome screen.

I then set up a root to `contact` in `routes.php` like this

```
Route::get('contact', 'WelcomeController@contact');
```

and in the `WelcomeController.php` controller file I have created a method for my route like this.

```
public function contact()
{
    return 'Hello Mo';
}
```

Entering `http://laravel5/` Gives me the Laravel5 Welcome screen

But. on entering the following in the browser address

`http://laravel5/contact`

I am presented with this screen

[image]

Has it got something to do with how my `VirtualHost` is set up?

Comment: You wrote you use `http://learning-laravel-5/contact` to access controller, shouldn't it be `http://laravel5/contact` ?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek. Yes sorry typo. see update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you enable mod_rewrite in apache.

How to enable mod_rewrite

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then you must point your url to the ServerName. In your case it should be

```
ServerName laravel5
```

So, the url must be

```
http://laravel5/contact
```

Comment: Im using windows and wamp. After enabling apache `mod_rewrite`, apache does not want to start up.

Comment: Go to httpd.conf on /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache and see if the LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so line is un-commented (without the # at the beginning) 

Maybe your httpd.conf has error. That why apache cannot start